# Is there a way to simulate content_for in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the content_for tag of rails, but I was wondering if there's a way to simulate this:

```
- content_for (:modal) do
    = render 'agreements/edit'
```

On javascript because right now I have this:

```
  - @agreements.each do |agreement|
    %tr{id: agreement.id}
      %td
        %p.agreement-discount= agreement.amount
      %td
        %p.agreement-name= agreement.name
      %td
        %p.agreement-size= agreement.total_students
      %td
        %p.agreement-size= agreement.agreement_service_students.active.size
      %td
        %a.button-assign{value: "#{agreement.id}"}
          %p.blue-text= t('service.button_assign')
      %td.table-options-icons
        - if agreement.is_assigned?
          .col-xs-12
            %p.icon-full-info-full{ title: t("message.fail_edit_destroy_agreement")}
        - else
          .col-xs-6
            %a.icon-full-pen-full.js-edit-agreement{href: "#", id: "#{agreement.id}"}
          .col-xs-6
            = link_to agreement, method: :delete, id: "agreement-destroy-#{agreement.id}",
                  data: { confirm: t('confirm_delete.agreement', agreement: agreement.name) } do
              .icon-full-trash-full.small-profile

    - content_for (:modal) do
      = render 'agreements/edit'
```

If I remove the content_for tag the modal won't open.

Thanks!

Comment: Is javascript who opens it, you just render it (probably hidden) so that is in place when you trigger it.

Comment: why do you want to simulate it in javascript? what's not working about your code?

Comment: As a note it's a bad habit to separate the parens from the method call. Use `content_for(:modal)` or `content_for :modal` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I need to simulate this because I'm gonna change my table to a datatable (getting al the info from ajax) and I can't use the content_for :modal on the datatable class (from this example http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?language=en&view=asciicast) @maxpleaner

Comment: You have a couple options. You can load the HTML from the server through AJAX. Or you could make hidden sections in the HTML and unhide them with customized content when the data from the AJAX comes in. Or you could opt to completely build your HTML inside Javascript using a front end framework. I think you should give it a try to implement in Javascript as best you know how and then post your attempt here; it will be easier to help that way.